# Using USB ports for reading & writing data in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core

Do you know a way that how can I communicate USB ports in .net core 2.0? I tried to use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort but it did not worked for me. I tired to get ports but it returned nothing. Could you please help me about that? I am trying to send some print commands to a pos printer(EPSON TM-T88V). This printer supports both serial and usb port. I did an implementation for EPSON TM-M30 (wifi printer) and it is working properly and I want to use same commandset for the other printer but it has just usb and serial port, I cannot communicate with that printer(TM-T88V) over ethernet or wifi. I could not share my all implementation for the wifi printer but as I mentioned I just send simple print command like below over socket and I want to do same thing both over usb and serial ports.

```
Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            clientSock.NoDelay = true;
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x");
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
            clientSock.Connect(remoteEP);
            var enc = Encoding.ASCII;
            // Send Lines
            byte[] bEsc = new byte[4];
            bEsc[0] = 0x0A;
        bEsc[1] = 0x0A;
        bEsc[2] = 0x0A;
        bEsc[3] = 0x0A;
        clientSock.Send(bEsc);
```

Comment: Most modern PCs don't have serialports until you plug in some USB2ComPort device.

Comment: Also, specify exactly  which packages you use.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, yes you are right I have a usb printer (pos printer) and I am trying to send some print commands over usb port but I could not a way in managed .net core. I tried System.IO.Ports package.

Comment: A USB printer isn't usually a serial printer. You will have to add much more details (printer model) , code and actual/expected results.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  Hi, I added some extra comments I hope that is sufficient for you.

Comment: A printer on a USB cable could use a virtual COM port but it doesn't have to, and most likely this one doesn't. Use other tools (Device Manager, HyperTerminal) to check if you can see a SerialPort. When not, this approach is dead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman On my local computer there is no serial port. If you have any opinion or suggestion about how can I communicate over usb with this printer in .net core I would be appreciated.

Comment: No, I don't. Consult the manuals, google with that printer name.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do that with `aspnet core >3.x`. I've done it with a `ppu-700II`.

```
using System;using System.IO.Ports;
namespace hello_serialport
{ 
  class Program
  {        
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {             
      // Get a list of serial port names.             
      string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();             
      Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");             
      // Display each port name to the console.             
    foreach(string port in ports)             
    {                 
    Console.WriteLine(port);             
    }             
      Console.ReadLine();        
    }    
  }
}
```

Don't forget to set the baud rate, databits, stopbits, parity and port name before opening the port.

```
private static SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();
*set settings and open*
*send commands in hexa*
*close port*
```

I'm interested in knowing on how to communicate with that printer also(EPSON TM-M30). Can you provide me some aid with that?